# why "grep -v" or "tail -f" stop my program's output?

Tags: bash, grep

I have a server for Euro Truck Simulator 2 which is called by the following command:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH='$ORIGIN/../../linux64' eurotrucks2_server
```

When the server is running, sometimes I get these lines in console (and I'd like to hide them):

```
src/steamnetworkingsockets/clientlib/steamnetworkingsockets_sdr_common.h (564) : m_pServer->m_nReplyTimeoutsSinceLastRecv == 0
```

But whenever I append a `| grep -v "Timeout"` or `| grep -v "steamnetworkingsockets"`, the server output is truncated at precisely this line:

```
Setting breakpad minidump AppID = 227300
```

I also tried the `--line-buffered` option for grep without luck and also removing grep and using `| tail -f` has the same result..

Here's the whole output: https://paste.debian.net/hidden/290d8573/

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The `|` only catches the *standard output* (stdout) stream; these messages are going to the *standard error* (stderr) stream. Using `grep` to hide the stderr messages is a [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).

### Solution to the Y problem

To `grep` both at the same time you need to forward stderr stream to stdout with `2>&1`, e.g.,

```
eurotrucks2_server 2>&1 | grep -v "Timeout"
```

### Solutions to the X problem

- Discard stderr output with `2>/dev/null`, e.g.,

  ```
  eurotrucks2_server 2>/dev/null
  ```
- Forward (append) stderr output to a log file with `2>>/path/to/error.log`, e.g.,

  ```
  eurotrucks2_server 2>>/var/log/eurotrucks2_server_error.log
  ```

Comment: I'm sorry but it still stops at the same point.

Comment: this seems to work: 2> >(grep -v "Timeout"). Still waiting a bit to see if something (which shouldn't) shows up.

Comment: yeah, not working still, I see all of the content which should be hidden.